# Why isn't my Where working as I think it should?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get some data from a database whose results can be more than one row.

I've the following code for that:

```
public System.Linq.IQueryable<Users> getUser2(string idUser)
{
    try
    {
        using (Entities c = new Entities())
        {
            c.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            c.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            return c.Users.Include("Empresas").Where(x => x.Login == idUser && x.Empresas.Activa == true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to get any result, it shows something like a badly formed Iqueryable, I mean if I expand its results view I can see a message that says "ObjectContext instance has been eliminated and cannot be used for operations that need a connection" If I try to access any Users element with the function ElementAt(index) I get an IndexOutOfBounds error as it looks like it has no data if watched on debug mode.

I've deduced that it's Where fault because this code Works fine in returning the first user it finds that fulfills the condition:

```
public Users getUser(string idUser)
{
    try
    {
        using (Entities c = new Entities())
        {
            c.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            c.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            return c.Users.Include("Empresas").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == idUser && x.Empresas.Activa == true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Does that Where work differently than what I think I should? If then, how could I get several data that fulfills the conditions I'm passing the same as in getUser but for several rows?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: "it shows something like a badly formed Iqueryable" - what *exactly* do you mean? "If I try to access any Users element with the function ElementAt(index) I get an error" - what error? Please be more specific.

Comment: Show your `Users` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the result,  so after the "where" statement add. ToList() which will enumerate and execute the query against your database. FirstOrDefault is executing the query thats why you get a result.

You need to check the deferred methods and understand how they work.

**EDIT**
The following are some links to show you the deference between the Deferred method vs Immediate methods in LINQ

1- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=750

2- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627081/LINQ-Deferred-Execution-Lazy-Evaluation

3- http://visualcsharptutorials.com/linq/deferred-execution

Hope that helps.